# Why is my commit button not going through its for loop?

Tags: c#

I currently have an insert button that allows three people into an array, once the commit button is clicked it should go through the array instantiated by the insert button and insert the Students into my SQL database. Currently it only inserts the first student inserted into the array. Also, I know there is no form of security for this, I am moving through lessons and haven't gotten to any parameterized queries or cross site scripting yet. Will update once I get to it.

```
protected void Commit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 0;
    a = (int)Session["count"];

    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection
    {
        ConnectionString = @"Server =LocalHost;Database=Lab1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    };
    sc.Open();
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
    insert.Connection = sc;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {            
        DateTime Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text);
        resultMessage.Text = "";
        maxID++;
        DateTime queryLastUpdated = Student.newStudents[i].LastUpdated;
        queryLastUpdated.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");
        if (MiddleInitial.Text == "")
        {
            try
            {                        
                insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] ([FirstName],[LastName],[HouseNumber],[Street],[CityCounty],[HomeState],[Country],[Zip],[DateOfBirth]" +
                ",[LastUpdatedBy],[LastUpdated],[PropertyID]) VALUES ('" +
                    Student.newStudents[i].FirstName + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].LastName
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].HouseNumber
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].Street + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].CityCounty
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].State + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].Country
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].ZipCode + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text)
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].LastUpdatedBy + "', '" + queryLastUpdated
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].PropertyID + "')";
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                resultMessage.Text = "Error Clearing Database.";
            }                    
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] ([FirstName],[LastName],[MiddleName],[HouseNumber],[Street],[CityCounty],[HomeState],[Country],[Zip],[DateOfBirth]" +
                ",[LastUpdatedBy],[LastUpdated],[PropertyID]) VALUES ('" 
                    + Student.newStudents[i].FirstName + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].LastName
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].MiddleName + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].HouseNumber
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].Street + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].CityCounty
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].State + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].Country
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].ZipCode + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text)
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].LastUpdatedBy + "', '" + queryLastUpdated
                    + "', '" + Student.newStudents[i].PropertyID + "')";
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                resultMessage.Text = "Error Clearing Database.";
            }
        }
        Student.counter = 0;
        Array.Clear(Student.newStudents, 0, Student.newStudents.Length);
        Array.Clear(Student.studentCopy, 0, Student.studentCopy.Length);
    }
    sc.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `Session["count"];`?

Comment: At that point it is 2

Comment: Yeah it isn't an issue for this, I was using the same thing and a friend showed me that way of doing it.

Comment: This is a great chance to practice using the debugger.  Step through the loop, watching the variable s change. You do that and you'll see the problem

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with your code is that you are clearing the array after the very first iteration of your loop:

```
Array.Clear(Student.newStudents, 0, Student.newStudents.Length);
```

That way your array now holds a whole number of empty objects (default for your class) ([Array.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=netframework-4.8)) - and there is no point of inserting anything meaningful from this.

On top of that a couple of suggestions:

1. Use "using", it will make your life much easier :)
2. You dont really need the if condition in your loop - I could not spot a real difference in sql commands (but might be wrong tho..). General rule of thumb for development should be "readability and simplicity rule the world" :)
3. As mentioned in comments - if you are working with an array directly - check its length rather then store it in a session.
4. `queryLastUpdated.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");` doing nothing for you. You need to store the string somewhere, if you want to use it,

And lastly, for stackoverflow it is better to post a minimal amount of required code, it will make your questions much better!

Comment: The array.clear was the part that messed it all up, thank you for pointing that out! Also, thank you for the extra tips, I will try to implement them into my upcoming work.